# What does M mean in A400M Atlas?

Tags: military, airbus, transport-category

Atlas was the guy in Greek mythology that was literally carrying the world/planet in his shoulders. But was does "M" mean? Military? That's a guess, though...

Comment: That’s a good guess

Comment: I've never seen any mention of a specific meaning in EADS documentation, but as it's marketed exclusively (afaik) to military operators that's likely a correct assumption.

Comment: @jwenting indeed, only military operators to my knowledge too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the M, people would simply confuse the military cargo plane with the civil airliners that Airbus builds (e.g. A320, A380, etc).

Comment: I thought of that as well. But I was hoping to find a reference.